# use if condition to compare the password using python

Tags: python, html, mysql, apache, localhost

I have HTML form for getting the name and the password .And python codes are used to get that enter data and store in variable first_name and password.

For given name stored password is fetched from database using WHERE clause .
By using if condition I have tried to compare the password fetched from database and password entered from form.If they are equal then do some action .If not do some other condition .But the problem is i am not able to understand how to assign the if condition .
What i tried is as given below.:

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"
import cgitb ,cgi
import sys
import mysql.connector
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
password = form.getvalue('pass')
print (password)
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',port='8051',
                                       database='test',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='next')                                
cursor = conn.cursor()                                 
if conn.is_connected():
    print('Connected to MySQL database')
cursor.execute("""SELECT pass FROM tablename1 where  name = '%s'""" % (first_name))

for row in cursor():
    if(password == row):
        print("sucess")
    else:
        print("fail")
```

Please check my code.And give some suggestion.

Comment: You **should not** be doing this. Passwords shouldn't be stored and compared in plain text form, you should use salting and hashing. If you don't know what you're doing, I **strongly suggest** you use existing libraries rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it' s something like registration form where u can enter the details and password that password is stored in database .Later if u log in it will fetch the password from database and check current password is correct or not .This what i want do. But iam not getting what ur suggesting .

Comment: Can any body please check the syntax of using if and for is proper .Because it's not printing success also fail also

Comment: Yes, I know what you're trying to do, and I'm telling you **you're doing it the wrong way**. The answer shows you how to do it much better. As to why `password != row`, why not try to `print(repr(password))` and `print(repr(row))` to find out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user registers for the first time, you should save his password like this:

```
$password = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This should output something like `$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a`

And you should store it in your database.

Then you should verify passwords like this:

```
<?php
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq'; // you get it from your database

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) { // 'rasmuslerdorf' is what user entered
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Now, what is a hash? Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice).

EDIT: you mean something like this?

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ? and password= ?",
    (username, pass1))
found = cursor.fetchone()
if found:
    # user exists and password matches
else:
    # user does not exist or password does not match
```

Comment: what if i want to store password or name in database then fetch and compare.i am asking about comparing not validating .

Comment: I've edited the answer. Is this what you wanted to do?

Answer (score -2):

Haha here's my late answer,

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT Password FROM users WHERE username= '{username}';")
found = cursor.fetchone()
for row in found:
    if found == row:
        # user exists and password matches
    else:
        # user does not exist or password does not match
```

Comment: This question and its other answer are 8.5 years old. It's okay to answer old questions, but it's usually helpful if you can explain how your answer is better than what's already here. Why should we use this solution over the other one?

Comment: Also... `and password matches`—what part of this checks the user's password? Wouldn't this let anybody log in if they provide a valid username, with any password at all?